# Is there a way to change rules ad-hoc in Smash Ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

In *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate*, players can create custom rulesets and save them for further use. Is there a way to temporarily change the rules for one match (e.g. turn all items off), without creating and naming a new custom ruleset?

Comment: You can edit an existing rule-set and then edit it back...would that do what you want? You'd still need to change it back manually after the match is over though...

Comment: I doubt there is, but I really hope so, I would be enthused to know how to do this

Comment: Can you Copy Rulesets? If so you could dupe your rule set, make the changes and then delete the Dupe when you are done.

Comment: @Malco This would still be a lot of overhead. Why is there no menu like in Melee, where I could just quickly turn items on or off?

Comment: @DavidStockinger it would be added overhead but I don't think there is an easier way. New Smash is great when it comes to gameplay but there are a bunch QoL changes that could be made to smooth menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a rule set for only one game. You can edit the mode and change whatever you want and then after the game go back and change everything.